# 4 way circuit, need to reduce it to 3 way

Tags: switch, light

I have a 4 way circuit (two 3way switches and one 4way ) controlling one light in my back patio. I would like to add a second light and use one of the 3 existing switches to control it, turning the original light into a 3 way circuit . Thanks for the help .     [image]

Comment: Thanks, I’ve added a picture of wiring . My question is , how do I go about wiring one of the existing switches to control a new light fixture ? Then rewire the remaining 2 switches to continue controlling the original light.

Comment: Did you make that diagram exactly to your wiring or is it a general diagram you found online?  Just asking because it looks so good.

Comment: If your situation matches that diagram, all the wires currently in place are dedicated to that switch circuit. You can't branch off it. You'll need a new power run to the new/repurposed switch.

Comment: **Which light, exactly**, do you want to control from which switch? And we really, really need to know whether you selected that diagram carefully because it does match your wiring, or just grabbed a random one off the Internet.  The solution depends on it.

Comment: It almost looks like one of mine @jphi1618, except I don't draw green or ramped Romex, I like green backgrounds coz ground. And I **always** color the travelers yellow or blue. Always. Always. Otherwise it's Egyptian spaghetti.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the actual boxes involved?